# how do you "use" library version numbers

Tags: google-apps-script

I am playing with the concept of a Google Apps Script "library".

I have created a library. 
I set up its initial version (it assigned version #1).
I added some additional functions to the library,
and updated the version number to #2.

I then accessed my testing spreadsheet. I expected to
see a "version #2" available for selection. But
all I could see is version #1. So I deleted the resource,
thinking the spreadsheet did not have access to the new version. I 
obtained the project's "key" and did a "select" on the key.
The same line was included. When I went to view the versions
in the drop-down list, only the first version (#1) appeared.
I selected that version (I had no choice).
I ran the test which accesses the newly added functions
and they worked (even under version #1).

Does setting a new version have any effect?
Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want your script to be able to get the project version that it is running within then please go "star" @Edo 's corresponding [feature request (#1369)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1369).  Your star equals a vote for this feature.  (The request is in the official Apps-Script issue tracker, [according](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing-features) to the official Google Apps Script Support page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it just takes some time for the updates on your library to show up everywhere else. Have you tried it again after waiting 5-10 minutes?

Comment: A day later, version #2 does show in the list. However, the new functions were already available yesterday under version #1. Maybe versions only count for replacing same named functions. Maybe there is no need to exclude "new" functions from older versions? I would hope there is tighter control over which functions are associated with which versions.